# How can I communicate Raspberry Pi and Arduino (in both ways) using a 10-15m distance wires?

Tags: arduino, communication

I am starting a personal project of home automation and I have a raspberry pi and an arduino Uno board.

I want communicate raspberry pi and my arduino where my raspberry should be able to write and read signals to and from arduino.

The distance between them I think its going to be something around 10 to 15 meters.

What do I need for it? what kind of wires or other components I'll need to achieve my goal? I repeat: I do not want to communicate raspberry pi and arduino wirelessly.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure but I think you could just run a USB cable and read and write to the Serial port?

Comment: What about the usb limitation of 5meters?

Comment: you're right -- I didn't know about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi and all microcontrollers used in the Arduinos natively support a number of standard protocols, e.g. [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) (often called "UART" on embedded platforms), [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus) and [I²C/TWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C), for each of which you will find plenty of tutorials.

RS-232 is [probably the most robust of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Disadvantages) when it comes to long transmission distances, but at the 10 to [15 meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232#Cables) you're expecting, you should reduce the bit rate to avoid transmission errors.

RS-232 in its simplest form only requires a common ground wire and one data wire per transmission direction.
You will be using RS-232 with TTL levels (0 Volt/+5 Volt instead of the up to -15 Volt/+15 Volt defined by the original standard).
Be aware however that the Raspberry Pi operates at 3.3 Volt, while the Arduino is likely to use 5 Volt — enough to damage the Pi — so you will need a level shifter of some sort. Since you're not going to need (or get) high speed anyway, a resistive voltage divider will be sufficient ([there are tutorials for that too](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/voltage-dividers)).

Answer (score 0):

Look into Motenio at lowpowerlab.com. This is an Arduino clone with a built-in 433 mHz radio. Use one motenio as a gateway to the Raspi via rs-232. Then you can have up to 127 other motenio's communicating via 433 mHz link to the motenio/Raspi hub.

I have this set up at my house, along with a webserver on the Raspbi. I have aan effective range thru brick walls of aprox. 700 ft. Works great!